# Displaying a single value from multiple values in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

First off, sorry for the title gore, I couldn't find a good title for my question. Anyways, I have a table that looks like this

```
 email | lang
----------------
 d@d.c | 1
 d@d.c | 2
 a@d.c | 2
 a@d.c | 2
 z@d.c | 1
```

I would like to return this

```
 email | lang
----------------
 d@d.c | 3
 a@d.c | 2
 z@d.c | 1
```

- If an email appears multiple times, it must appear only once in the results
- If an email appears multiple times and has a single lang, display the corresponding lang
- If an email appears multiple times and has multiple lang, display 3
- If an email appears once, display it

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work considering lang can't be called like that in the `THEN`

```
SELECT   email,
CASE     COUNT(lang)  WHEN 1 THEN lang ELSE '3' END
FROM     table
GROUP BY email
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this? Thanks

Comment: And you need to count DISTINCT lang.

Comment: Great that did it. Thanks a lot guys. `CASE COUNT(DISTINCT lang)  WHEN 1 THEN MAX(lang) ELSE '3' END`

Answer (score 0):

This code will definitely help you. use your table name in place of #tempP

```
select 
distinct
email,
(CASE WHEN (count(lang)>1) THEN lang ELSE (select SUM(lang) from #tempP where email=T.email) END) lang
from 
#tempP T
group by email,lang
```